# Changing Lucene analyzer for field based on language

Tags: lucene, multilingual, analyzer, indexwriter

I need to index documents based on document language, and for that I would like to use appropriate Analyzer. Is it anyhow possible to change analyzer for single field without closing and reopening IndexWriter, since that is apparently costly task, and language could change quite frequently? 
Or is there a better way of handling multiple languages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the appropriate analyzer into [IndexWriter.addDocument](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#addDocument(java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer))

Comment: Thank you, don't know how I missed that one :)

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#addDocument(java.lang.Iterable)) for Lucene 9.6.0, it seems that this API is no longer there. Any idea if it's possible to have a per document analyzer?